# Como calcular e mostrar o tempo de duração de um vídeo

Tags: php, html-meta-tag

Gostaria de saber como eu posso calcular e mostrar o tempo de  duração de vídeos online que estejam em arquivos de media por URL remota usando no casso esta URL http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/13277141.mp4 para dar o tempo de duração do vídeo no caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro que você dê olha olhada no `getID3`

Você pode acessar a pagina [neste link!](http://www.getid3.org/)

o `getID3` é uma clase php para ver os atributos de um arquivo, veja o exemplo a seguir;

```
<?php
Include ("getid3/getid3.php");
$filename="nome_do_video.mp4";
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analize($filename);
echo $file['playtime_string'];

?>
```

Se houver duvidas consulte a pagina `demo` no site do `getID3`

Comment: Jesus! Eu to tentando implementar isso e não funciona! O primeiro erro está no analize.. é ANALYZE, depois disso não importa qual vídeo eu traga pro analyze ele sempre diz que não conhece o index: playtime_string. Será que você me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho uma solução em **Javascript**. Sei que você queria em `PHP`, mas essa forma abaixo é mais aconselhável, pois trabalha diretamente com as propriedades do vídeo sem a necessidade de **API**, **EXECUTE O CÓDIGO ABAIXO**(`comentários no código`):

```js
//Criando as funcionalidades do video
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause()
{ 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
else 
 myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function muteUnMute()
{ 
    if( !myVideo.muted)
 myVideo.muted='muted';
else

myVideo.muted=false;
} 

//Criando as propriedades do video

var videoStartTime = 0;
var durationTime = 0;

myVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  
  //DETERMINADO PONTO DE PARTIDA DO VÍDEO
  videoStartTime = 0;
  
  //DURAÇÃO DO VÍDEO PROGRAMADA
  durationTime = 10;
  this.currentTime = videoStartTime;
}, false);

//Função que conta o progresso do vídeo
myVideo.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  
  //Setando na div o a duração do vídeo
  var div = document.getElementById('tempo');
  div.innerHTML = this.currentTime;
  
  //Condição para pausar o video em determinado tempo      
  if(this.currentTime > videoStartTime + durationTime){
    this.pause();
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center"> 
<h3>Contando o tempo: </h3><div id="tempo" style="color: red"></div>
 <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pausar</button> 
<button onclick="muteUnMute()">SemSom/comSom</button> 
     <br> 
<video id="video1" width="420">
 <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/13277141.mp4" type="video/ogg">
 Seu browser não suporta HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou olha só o teste que eu fiz http://jsfiddle.net/Ryumaru/rcuuqz7c/ o vídeo nem abre quanto mais mostra o valores de tempo.

Comment: `TENTE NO SEU SERVIDOR`. Aqui funciona e no liveweave. Taí um link no liveweave:  http://liveweave.com/lhvIuI